# Can't write image data to path. Intervention Image Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5, intervention

```
   public function newItem(Request $request){

        $image = $request->file('image');
        $img = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $watermark = Image::make('images/watermark.png');
        $destinationPath = public_path('/products');
        $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $img->resize(300, 365, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->insert($watermark, 'center');
        File::exists($destinationPath) or File::makeDirectory($destinationPath);
        $img->save($destinationPath.'/'.$img);
```

}

I keep getting **Can't write image data to path**
Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?
The question might seem duplicate, but other suggestions in similar questions did not work for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your error stack ?

Comment: Are permissions correct?

Comment: @RolfPedroErnst permissions are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of others that might have the same issue. This is how I solved it:

```
 $image = $request->file('image');
    $img = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

$watermark = Image::make('images/watermark.png');
$destinationPath = public_path('/products');
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300, 365, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->insert($watermark, 'center')->save($destinationPath.'/'.$img);
```

The mistake I was making was assigning Image::make() to a variable. You can look at my code here and the one above in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it's worked for me

```
public function newItem(){

    $image = Input::file('image');
    $destinationPath = '/products';
    $img = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $watermark = Image::make('images/watermark.png');
    $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
    $img->resize(300, 365, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })->insert($watermark, 'center');
    File::exists($destinationPath) or File::makeDirectory($destinationPath);
    $img->save($destinationPath.'/'.$img);
}
```

Comment: I'm using 5.2, Input class is no longer supported.

Comment: It is still supported I am also having a project written by 5.2 and it's working for me

Comment: Not sure if `Input` works with 5.2, but the problem is with Intervention image. Using Laravel inbuilt file upload works perfectly. `$request->file('image')->move($destinationPath, $img);`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to create mentioned path folders (passing with image save) in laravel public folder. This will work automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody use File Facade:

```
    File::exists($destinationPath) or File::makeDirectory($destinationPath);
```

You have to remember that if your `$destinationPath` contains more than 1 folder, you have to set 2nd & 3rd parameters like `$mode` & `$recursive` to create final destination folder and prepare directory for file upload.

Example:

```
    File::exists($imagePath) or File::makeDirectory($imagePath, 777, true);
```